# django selenium fails to load localhost

Tags: python, django, selenium

I have a simple code for testing:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

Run it: python3 functional_tests.py (or ./manage.py test functional_tests)

Firefox shows page: 
Title: Problem loading page
Body: Unable to connect ...

If I run: "./manage.py runserver" everything is fine, I can see "django hello page" in my browser. Also if i try "browser.get('http:// microsoft. com')" it works just fine.

Same issue with Chrome and the same on Windows 7 x64 and Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Selenium 2.47.3
Chromedriver 2.19

Any clues?

**UPD.**

Ok. I didn't run the server.
But i had same problem with LiveServerTestCase.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class GeneralFunctionalTests(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_navigate_site(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        assert 'Django' in self.browser.title
```

Thank You!

Comment: Are you running your Django server at the time you're running the test? Is this a programmatic test or just a script you're running? If it's programmatic, check out the Django LiveServer test case. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase

Comment: You are right. I updated post. Please take a look on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case-1 : Accessing `'http://localhost:8000'` without running Django server**

In the first case, the browser is trying to access a url on the localhost. This requires a Django server to be running alongside for the browser to open the url correctly. Since you are not running a Django server alongside with it, you get the message `Unable to connect ..`

**Case-2 : Accessing `'http://localhost:8000'` while running the Django server alongside**

When you run a Django server alongside it, the browser will be able to access the localhost url as there is a server running at port 8000 which will listen to request from the browser. So, you are able to see the Django `Hello Page`.

**Case-3: Accessing `'http://microsoft.com`**

Same is the case with accessing `Microsoft's` website using selenium. There is a server running on their end which listens to requests made to `http://microsoft.com` due to which the page gets loaded.

**What you can also do?**

You can also use a [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) for testing.

From the [docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase)

> it launches a live Django server in the background on setup, and shuts
>   it down on teardown.

Comment: Ok. I didn't run the server :) I spent like few hours on it. I started with  LiveServerTestCase and had same problem - localhost didn't load. So i try to make it easier and made stupid mistake. So, what is the problem with LiveServerTestCase? I'm going to update my post with proper code right now

Comment: Or maybe I should ask another question about LiveServerTestCase?

Comment: I think it would be more useful if it was a separate question. :) Also, what error you were getting from that code?

Comment: Try defining `setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()` i the same fashion as they have done in the [example] if that helps. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase)

Comment: I've posted a new question about [LiveServerTestCase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831049/django-selenium-liveservertestcase)