# django selenium LiveServerTestCase

Tags: python, django, selenium

I have an issue with selenium and LiveServerTestCase.
When I run `./manage.py test functional_tests` it loads a page "Title: Problem loading page. Body: Unable to connect..."

functional_tests.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class GeneralFunctionalTests(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_navigate_site(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        assert 'Django' in self.browser.title
```

I tried to setUp and tearDown using classmethod:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super(MySeleniumTests, cls).setUpClass()
    cls.browser = WebDriver()
...
```

Result is the same.
But I could load any other pages in web with `self.browser.get('http://example.com')`.
Selenium is up to date.

Thank You!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**What you are doing wrong?**

[`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) runs the live server on port `8081` by default and you are trying to access the url on port `8000`. Now, since there is no server listening on port 8000, the browser is not able to load the page.

From the [`LiveServerTestCase` docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase)

> By default the live server’s address is **`localhost:8081`** and the full
>   URL can be accessed during the tests with **`self.live_server_url`.**

**What you need to do instead?**

**Option 1: Changing the url**

You can change the url to point to `8081` port.

```
def test_can_navigate_site(self):
    self.browser.get('http://localhost:8081') # change the port
    assert 'Django' in self.browser.title
```

**Option 2: Using the live server url**

You can use the `live_server_url` in your test case as [@yomytho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3364711/yomytho) has also pointed out.

```
def test_can_navigate_site(self):
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url) # use the live server url
    assert 'Django' in self.browser.title
```

**Option 3: Running the live server on port 8000**

Until Django 1.10, you can pass the port number as `8000` to the test command via the `--liveserver` option to run the liveserver on port 8000.

```
$ ./manage.py test --liveserver=localhost:8000 # run liveserver on port 8000
```

This parameter was [removed in Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.11/#liveservertestcase-binds-to-port-zero), but now you can set the port on your test class:

```
class MyTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    port = 8000

    def test_can_navigate_site(self):
        ....
```

Comment: Thank you for help! Great explanation!

Comment: Is the ``liveserver`` parameter default? ``./manage.py help test`` show nothing about it.

Comment: Yes, its a default parameter. Check this link(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-liveserver)

Comment: @ikreb That option existed until Django 1.10, but was removed in 1.11. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.11/#liveservertestcase-binds-to-port-zero

Comment: --liveserver doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to get the wrong server address : [by default, the address is `http://localhost:8081`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase).

The best way to access the right address is to use `self.live_server_url` :

```
    def test_can_navigate_site(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
```

Answer (score 6):

For users who are using `Django 1.11` ([`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/)):

> The live server listens on `localhost` and binds to port `0` which uses a free port assigned by the operating system. The server’s URL can be accessed with  `self.live_server_url` during the tests.

So... use `self.live_server_url`.

Comment: Dang it. Really nicely spotted. Does it bind the port "randomly" due to previous security issues?