# How to PATCH Django Test Server with cURL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my API, I have the following dynamics:

1. `POST` a processing request to the API.
2. Do some processing in the background.
3. When the processing is done, a computer will `PATCH` the API's original request `status` field with `cURL`.

These steps *do* work when I test them with a normal server, i.e., `python manage.py runserver`. However, when I try to *automate tests* within `Django`, I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

Port `80` is what is specified under the [`django.test.client`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py) module with `'SERVER_PORT': '80'`, so I really don't get why that wouldn't work.

Comment: [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44798993/4756173) has been most useful so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this can be considered a full answer yet because I haven't tested it enough yet. But, apparently, Django's `TestCase` dummy server is somewhat simple for more specific cases. You could instead use [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/) for something more robust. (If you want more info, check out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44798993/4756173).)

Within the `LiveServerTestCase` class, you will find the `self.live_server_url` attribute, which will have the address of where the server actually is. The port assigned to it will be somewhat random apparently due to security reasons. Then, finally, somehow, you can manage to pass the info into your `PATCH` operation.