# How can I handle selenium and geckodriver install error?

Tags: django, selenium, firefox, tdd, geckodriver

I ran the following code by installing `selenium` and `django` module.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000') 
assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

For the `selenium` module, I need `geckodriver` for firefox browser.
So, I installed geckodriver by different ways - 1. npm, 2. brew, 3. direct install (download from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and move it to `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`. All the ways did not work for the above test code.

I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser.get('http://localhost:8000') 
  File "/Users/kiyeonj/opt/anaconda3/envs/tdd_practice/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/kiyeonj/opt/anaconda3/envs/tdd_practice/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/kiyeonj/opt/anaconda3/envs/tdd_practice/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=http%3A//localhost%3A8000/&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20establish%20a%20connection%20to%20the%20server%20at%20localhost%3A8000.
```

Please let me know what the problem is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a gecko driver as well.

You can download from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.29.1)

and put it into a folder, preferably where you have your `.py files`

and then use it like this :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "D:\geckodriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

**PS :**

```
executable_path = 'full file path to your gecko driver'
```

Comment: Your previous url https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/ether-metamask/ is working, but http://localhost:8000 is not working...

Comment: Oh, I resolved it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828943/django-selenium-fails-to-load-localhost). After running the django server, getting localhost is working. Thanks!